# g++ -c main.cpp компилирую как в doc, но пишет ошибку main.cpp:7:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(int, int)’

Tags: c++, sfml

Вот пример кода: (из doc)

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main () {

    sf::RenderWindow window (sf::VideoMode(200,200), "SFML works!");

    return 0;
}
```

**$: g++ -c main.cpp**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем же проблема ? не могу понять...

Comment: @andreymal, Не помогает даже так: sf::

Comment: Какая версия SFML?

Comment: @andreymal, 3.0.0

Comment: Тогда логично, что код из доков версии 2 совершенно не обязан работать в версии 3

Comment: @andreymal, Тц, блин понял. Спасибо

Comment: @andreymal, Еще один момент пожалуйста, я щас пытаюсь найти версию 3.0.0 с оф сайта? но там версия 3.0.0 нет... А как я скачал и собрал версию 3.0.0 ?

Comment: А это у вас спрашивать надо)

Comment: @andreymal, боже мой xD я представить даже не могу как так получилось...

Comment: @andreymal, а как так вообще возможно ? я написал в google, sfml github и зашел сюда, https://github.com/SFML/SFML отсюда и скачал и собрал...

Comment: и даже тут написано:

The 2.6.0 tag is the latest official SFML release and will be the last minor release in the 2.x series.

Comment: А предыдущую строчку вы специально проигнорировали? «The master branch contains work in progress for the next major version SFML 3»

Comment: @andreymal, блин получается там по умолчанию грузиться версия master ?

Comment: + версия master еще в разработке, получается пока рано изучать его ?

Comment: @andreymal, Я специально выбрал sfml потому что в нем реально по проще мне козалось что то сделать... SDL чтоле изучать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы не используете для классов SFML пространство имён "sf".

   ```
    sf::RenderWindow window (sf::VideoMode(200,200), "SFML works!");
   ```
2. Судя по ошибкам g++, Вы используете нестабильную версию ветки Github "master". Конструктор класса sf::VideoMode в ветке master отличается от стабильной версии. Последняя стабильная версия - 2.6.1: [SFML-download](https://en.sfml-dev.org/download.php)